# Is there a way to make SVG element wrap its content?

Tags: html, svg

I have a SVG element that I would like to translate. When I translate it partially off the left edge, I would like the clipped portion to be rendered on the right edge (wrapped horizontally) and vice versa. Is this possible?

Comment: If what your asking for is a similar effect to the popular _snake_ game, then *yes* this is possible but please provide more information or a visual example.

Comment: basically if I have a shape like [====], when it moves off the left edge, I would like the screen to be something like ==]      [==, where it wraps.

Comment: I see, sure - I'll write up an answer but what you might want to do is get the width of the screen or view and make two clones of the svg one screen or view width either side of the original. This should provide the effect.

Comment: I meant is there any performant/native way to do this. I need something really performant, because there will be a ton of elements in the SVG. I was hoping there is some API that just tells the rendering engine to do the wrapping.

Comment: Assuming `<1000 * clone` elements this should render without issue, and work in a simple fashion.

Comment: I'm rendering >20k elements, so I can't afford to clone the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way in SVG to do this. If there are any elements partially off the edge, then you are going to have to add clones of them at the opposite edge. And possibly up to three clones, if it hits a corner.

Comment: ok, I just wanted to know if there is a fast/native way to do this. I was thinking that it would be simple for them to implement since it's all a image buffer underneath.